# Read fcm notification title and text inside MainActivity of android app when notification is tapped from status bar?

Tags: android, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to read the title and body of the notification that is clicked from the status bar. I'm able to successfully get notification payload sent through FCM using `Intent.Extras.GetString("key1")` inside my *MainActivity*. I've tried to get title using:

```
   var text = Intent.GetStringExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText);
   var title = Intent.GetStringExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraTitle);
```

But both `title` and `text` are null. Is there some other API that returns this information? If not, how can I read these?

Comment: You can get the title in the `OnMessageReceived` by `message.GetNotification().Title` and then pass it to your activity.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT but since my app is not active when the notification arrives, how would I receive OnMessageReceived callback? Am I missing something here?